# Two Word City Lookup With Zippopotam.us

Tags: api, rest, geolocation

I'm trying to retrieve the zip code for a particular city using zippopotam.us however I cannot find any documentation on how to format cities that have two words in their name ie New York, NY or New Haven, CT. I'm sure this is a simple answer I just cannot find any documentation on it.

I have tried `/newyork`, `/new-york`, and `/new_york` but none return successfully. Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

Example successful api call: `api.zippopotam.us/us/ma/belmont`

Comment: Can you show the whole URL you are trying to access?

Comment: I've added that to my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I was trying it out too and found out that you just need to use the space `%20`.

```
http://api.zippopotam.us/us/ny/new%20york
```

or

```
http://api.zippopotam.us/us/ny/new york
```

Other example:

```
http://api.zippopotam.us/us/ny/Niagara%20Falls
```